# реализация автоматического совершения однотипных действий в Windows

Tags: windows, командная-строка

Во первых - как я понял, можно автоматизировать некоторые действия в Windows, например, добавлять фотографии с определенным расширением (это только пример, речь идет не только об этом) в папки по какому то правилу.
Во вторых - я понял, что это можно сделать, например, с помощью командной строки.
Тогда вопрос в том, как это сделать. А так как циклы в командной строке писать недостаточно, то есть тут нужно не только знание её синтаксиса, то у меня возникает более общий вопрос - как называются общие умения реализации таких действий (понятно, что не только программирование, но и откуда взять умения именно для такой автоматизации)?

Comment: Такое умение называется - навыки администрирования Windows. Читайте профильную литературу, чтобы понимать, какой инструментарий есть. Соответственно, станет ясно, что следует изучить, чтобы научиться пользоваться инструментарием.